# How to retrieve Safari's Complete Browsing History Programmatically?

Tags: windows, macos, browser, safari, browser-history

**I am developing a tool to extract people's web visits on Mac and Windows** (history on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari). I have successfully retrieved history generated by Chrome and Firefox. However, **I am having trouble retrieve the complete browsing history on Safari.**

**I have done some searches and know that, on Mac, Safari stores history records in these two files**:

- /Users//Library/Safari/**History.plist** (storing the "last visit" time of a page and visit count)
- /Users//Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/**Cache.db** (storing blob cache data, URL, timestamp).

Reference:
http://www.appleexaminer.com/MacsAndOS/Analysis/HowTo/SafariBrowserAnalysis/SafariBrowserAnalysis.html

Originally, I was planning to use the information from these two files (or just the Cache.db) to re-construct the complete browsing history on Safari. **However, after examining the cache.db for a few times, I realize that it might not store all the records.**

For example, **I have tried to visit Google** through 1) typing in the URL in the address bar and 2) using bookmarks to access the page. **Both of them leave records with no entries like "http://www.google.com/".** **The closest one is "www.google-analytics.com", with a long list of parameters following after**, but I assume that this could potentially also be records generated when I visit other web sites that also use Google Analytics, so I cannot use this to say that it means someone visits Google.

**Did I miss something?**

**Are there other files that I should know to reconstruct the complete browsing history for Safari?**

**Do people have similar experience or know whether it is possible to reconstruct the complete browsing history for Safari?**

Comment: Can you please tell whether retrieving the information from the /Users//Library/Safari/History.plist will be accepted in Mac App Store?

Answer (score 3):

There're also Files stored in `/Users/user/Library/Caches/MetaData/Safari/History/`.

Comment: /Users/<REPLACE WITH YOUR USER>/Library/Caches/MetaData/Safari/History/

Comment: Can you please tell whether it will be accepted in Mac App Store?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Please follow following path then you will retrieve Browser history for iOS7 iPhone.

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications//Library/Safari/History.plist
```

In iOS7 safari app not a system app. When you open Applications folder then you can find history and other plist files.

Comment: Although I was originally asking about the history from Safari on a laptop/desktop computer, but thanks!